# Java Vector<int[]> reference of int[] or copy?

Tags: java, vector

I am creating combinations of integer-arrays and adding them to a Vector to store them for later use.
I do the combination by looping over the int[] and then add the element to the vector.

Does the Vector only add the reference to the int[] and therfore I will keep lots of references to the same int[] at the end or does it add a copy to the Vector?

Comment: Are you creating different instances of `int[]`? If so - you will end up with multiple references to different `int[]` objects. If you keep modifying and inserting the same `int[]` object - you will only have 1 object and multiple references to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arrays, including `int[]` are `Object`s in Java. This means that your `Vector` is holding references to your `int[]` elements.

However, I suggest you use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` or `Collections.synchronizedList` if you really need a synchronized version of a `List`.

Comment: So the ArrayList stores the array as a copy instead of reference?

Comment: To be entirely correct, it is a copy of a reference. It is storing references, anyway, like for any other objects.